# Getting Error vhen using $get ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Hi in my master page I have inserted the following javascript

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/MainStyle.css" />
<script type = "text/javascript">

function ClientItemSelected(sender, e) {
    $get("<%=hfCustomerId.ClientID %>").value = e.get_value();

}
```

In my content page I have an AutocompleteExtender this this is the code

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCustomer" runat="server">
      </asp:TextBox>
      <ajx:AutoCompleteExtender ServiceMethod="SearchCustomers" MinimumPrefixLength="2"
          CompletionInterval="100" EnableCaching="false" CompletionSetCount="10" TargetControlID="txtCustomer"
          ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" FirstRowSelected="false" OnClientItemSelected="ClientItemSelected">
      </ajx:AutoCompleteExtender>
      <asp:HiddenField ID="hfCustomerId" runat="server" />
       <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" 
          onclick="btnSubmit_Click"  />
```

But when I am compiling I am getting this error

```
Compilation Error 
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. 
Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code
appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'hfCustomerId' does not exist in the current context

Source Error:
Line 11:     <script type = "text/javascript">
Line 12:     function ClientItemSelected(sender, e) {
Line 13:         $get("<%=hfCustomerId.ClientID %>").value = e.get_value();
Line 14:         
Line 15:     }
```

There is anything I am missing..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hfCustomerId` is in the aspx page not in the paster page so you can't directly reference it.

Here's a guide: [How to: Reference ASP.NET Master Page Content](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxwa0ff0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Is it possible to place my js script in content page..?

Comment: Yes it is, and it is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a var in javascript on content page where actual control(hidden field with id hfCustomerId) exists like:

```
 var ddlFldDataID = $("<%= ddlFldData.ClientID %>");
```

Use this variable instead of direct id in master page like

```
function ClientItemSelected(sender, e) {
    $('#' + ddlFldDataID.selector).val() = e.get_value();
}
```

Please note you must have referenced jquery.